# Como poner un calendar a mi campo input con javascript, trabajo con .net

Tags: javascript, jquery, .net

Mi código de mi clase ModificacionFechasPagoPensiones.js, tiene lo siguiente:

```
/*Fecha Inicio*/
$("form#frmModificacionFechasPagoPensiones input[id='txtFechaInicio']").attr("data-validation", "custom, required, length");
$("form#frmModificacionFechasPagoPensiones input[id='txtFechaInicio']").attr("data-validation-length", "max10");
$("form#frmModificacionFechasPagoPensiones input[id='txtFechaInicio']").attr("maxlength", 10);
$("form#frmModificacionFechasPagoPensiones input[id='txtFechaInicio']").blur(function () {
    var FechaInicio = $(this).val();
    $(this).val(FechaInicio);
});
$("form#frmModificacionFechasPagoPensiones label[for='FechaInicio']").append("&nbsp;<span class='required' aria-required='true'>*</span>");

$("form#frmModificacionFechasPagoPensiones input[id='txtFechaInicio']").each(function (index) {
    $(this).attr("data-validation-error-msg-container", "#error_FechaInicio");
});
```

Mi codigo de mi clase ModificacionFechasPagoPensiones.cshtml, tiene lo siguiente:

```
<div class="space-4"></div>
<div class="form-group">
    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.FechaInicio, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "col-sm-3 control-label" })
    <div class="col-sm-9">
        @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.FechaInicio, new { id = "txtFechaInicio", placeholder = "FechaInicio", @class = "form-control", Type = "date" }) 
        <div id='error_FechaInicio' name='error_FechaInicio'>&nbsp;</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Puse un Type de tipo date,  si me pone el calendar, pero cuando yo le doy clic en un icono de lapiz modificar a una tabla que me trae una consulta y quiero modificar un registro en automatico me pasa la informacion en mi pantalla de modificar en mi pantalla de modificar tengo un campo Fecha Inicio y es un input, a ese input quiero agregarle un calendario para que cuando se modifique una fecha lo gana seleccionando la fecha desde el calendar, eh leido que con un datepicker, pero la verdad intente y no me sale.

Espero puedan ayudarme, saludos.

Answer (score 0):

Podes instalar jQueryUI desde Nuget y agregas las referencias en tu  BundleConfig
y en tu vista bastaría con tener algo así.

```js
@section Scripts {  
  
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryui")  
@Styles.Render("~/Content/cssjqryUi")  
  
 <script type="text/javascript">  
     $(document).ready(function () {  
         $('input[type=datetime]').datepicker({  
             dateFormat: "dd/M/yy",  
             changeMonth: true,  
             changeYear: true
         });  
  
     });  
</script>  
  
}
```

[Ejemplo aqui](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/ee01e6/how-to-add-jquery-datepicker-in-mvc/)